# SQL getting results from two tables in order by primary key

Tags: sql

In my query I want to get the rows from two different tables descending by their primary keys. They have two different keys so is it possible to be able to do this in one query?

Comment: Are you joining the 2 tables? Or are you using a union?

Comment: Does this mean all columns from both tables joined to each other ordered by one table's PK then the other table's PK? Does it mean one table's rows then the other table's rows stacked on top of each other ordered somehow? You need to provide us with some of the table schema, some sample inputs and the expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a little vague.  To "get rows from two different tables" you can do a JOIN, or you can do a UNION.

In the case of a JOIN:

```
SELECT a.id, a.something, b.id, b.something
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.aId = a.id
ORDER BY a.id, b.id
```

In the case of a UNION:

```
SELECT id, something
FROM (
    SELECT a.id. a.something FROM a
    UNION 
    SELECT b.id, b.something FROM b
) t
ORDER BY t.id
```

These are very different, but it seems like one of them will meet your needs.

(Note that UNION by default eliminates duplicates.  Use UNION ALL to keep duplicates.)

Comment: Thanks, sorry my question was quite vague but this does help a lot!

Comment: OK.  I just noticed that you want to sort descending, so of course use DESC in your ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       ( select a.pk, a.foo, a.bar from a
             union
             select b.pk, b.foo, b.bar from b
           ) c
ORDER BY   c.pk DESC;
```